# how can I clear the serial buffer prior to logging data from it?

Tags: raspbian, python, serial

I have a Pi B reading serial data over USB from an Arduino. A python sketch logs it to file. Whenever I initiate the logging program I get a bunch of garbage characters before the real data starts to come through. How can I prevent this. I have added code that waits for the buffer to be empty before logging begins but this only works sporadically.

```
import serial
import time

start = str(time.time())
fname = '/home/pi/datalogs/serialLog_UNIX' + start + '.txt'
#fname = '/home/pi/datalogs/serialLog2.txt'
fmode = 'a'
readOne = 0

# Windows version
#arduino = serial.Serial('COM1', 115200, timeout=.1)

# Linux version
arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 57600, timeout=.1)

inWait = 4

while inWait >0:
    arduino.flushInput()
    arduino.flush()
    arduino.flushOutput()
    inWait = arduino.inWaiting()

while True:
    data = arduino.readline()
    if readOne <0:
        readOne = readOne + 1
        data = ""
    elif data:
        print(data)
        outf = open(fname,fmode)
        outf.write(str(time.time()))
        outf.write(',')
        dataStr = str(data)
        dataStr = dataStr[2:]
        dataStr = dataStr[:-5]
        print(dataStr)
        outf.write(dataStr)
        outf.write('\n')
        outf.flush()
```

The first line of output looks like this:

1455004141.0082998,\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00ADC Range: +/- 6.144V (1 bit = 3mV)

1455004141.9993854,0,14.63,32

1455004143.4013093,2,14.43,32

1455004144.8026342,2,14.33,31

1455004146.2038803,2,14.49,31

1455004147.6060522,2,14.45,31

N.B. I have abbreviated the \x00 sequence as it is repeated a hundred times or more. You can see the end of one read before the pattern starts and you can see text - "ADC Range: +/- 6.144V (1 bit = 3mV)" - printed during void setup() of the Arduino sketch coming through immediately after the pattern and then the serial data starts coming through from void loop().

Cheers, 
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you disabled using the console for kernel logging, etc. (those numbers could be kernel timestamps)?  Although I think that "ADC Range: " thing *has* to be from the Arduino itself  since there's no ADC involved with the pi. So you might want to ask on [Arduino.SE](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) about that.

Anyway, make sure you've removed `console=ttyAMA0,115200` from `/boot/cmdline.txt` (and **do NOT leave any line breaks** in that file!).  Recently this has changed from `ttyAMA0` to `serial0` to make it compatible with the Pi 3; anything on a stock system that *isn't* `tty1` and includes a baud rate after a comma (`115200`) is probably for a serial console.

On wheezy you also have to remove:

```
T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
```

From the end of `/etc/inittab`.  That won't be there on jessie, as the new init system (systemd) will [start a login on the serial console](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-getty-generator.html) if it exists -- or not, if it doesn't (see in particular the "Serial Terminals" section of [this guide](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html) linked from that link).

You'll have to reboot after all that.

Comment: Its `systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service && systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service` to disable the serial getty on latest raspbian and archlinuxarm.

Comment: @MichaelDaffin  Actually you shouldn't have to do anything beyond removing the console from `cmdline.txt`; I've edited to reflect this, as I recently discovered the reason it didn't "seemed to be enabled" on the images I checked when this was first written is that systemd automatically starts a login getty if the kernel is using a serial console.  I do seem to remember it having entries in `/etc/systemd/system` directories for this at one point so perhaps that feature was added in the recent-ish past.

Comment: [See this archlinux wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/working_with_the_serial_console#GRUB2_and_systemd), keeping in mind that what GRUB does there is the same thing as is accomplished in `cmdline.txt`.  Primary documention is here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-getty-generator.html   This is definitely the case on current versions of Raspbian (tested).